# Is it insecure to describe my use of bcrypt to users?

Tags: security, passwords, password-protection, bcrypt, password-encryption

Password security is a concern for many.

I would like to include a "Learn about our password security" link that explains that we use bcrypt for password hashing and how it works.

Does making this information public cause any security worries or make my system less secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "System security should not depend on the secrecy of the implementation or its components."

What you are referring is [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). It is presumed that - except for the key - a crypto system should remain safe even if it is known. If you depend on the secrecy of the implementation, you should move to another system.

In your case of hashing, it should be put that if no backhash known method exists, the system is safe. The more people use your hashing algo, and the more it stands to the passing of time, the safer it is.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't make your system more secure since these algorithms are public and you want to avoid security through obscurity. However, the less an attacker knows about what you do and what you use the better.

The most likely scenario for this causing a problem is if the attacker finds out about a vulnerability in the library. If they don't know you use it, then they can't use it against you.

Comment: On the other hand if an attacker sees `$2a$12$Vhzm6NB2ryY6DVb5EqDLAegotqvO6Q2bgqcr0oGwfKkJ7tHookhVi`, it is quite obvious that i'm using `bcrypt`.